# Save data from datagrid to SQL all at once

Tags: c#, sql

I have a winform app in C# witch permits for editing of tables from my SQL database.
I managed to get the tables opened and edit them but when I save the data all lines get replicated.
Is there a way to do this but only edit the required fields or insert if a new one is added? I tried the update command but it won't work.

The code I use is:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO temp (data1, data2, data3, data4) VALUES(@c1,@c2,@c3,@c4)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C1", row.Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C2", row.Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C3", row.Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C4", row.Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You'll have to redefine your `SqlCommand` each time. It reuses the command each time in your loop.

Comment: @Bas thanks for the help, but can you be more specific please.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table? (is the primary key loaded in a row.Cell)

Comment: @Andrei Filimon Hi, yes i have a primary key, but it´s not loaded in a row.cell i tried loading it but still wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DataGridView is not bound to the DB (or it would already contain rows in the database which you don't want to insert again) you would be best off using a loop.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2) VALUES (@C1, @C2)", con))
        {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C1", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C2", SqlDbType.VarChar));
        con.Open();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows)
            {
            if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                cmd.Parameters["@C1"].Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                cmd.Parameters["@C2"].Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Old Style:** 
Use a DataSet as a data source for your DataGrid and [save using a DataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx).

**The 2017 Way:**
Go the [Entity Framework way](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx) and use native collection of typed object as a data source for your DataGrid.